# Express can't set headers after they're sent while downloading from mobile

Tags: node.js, express, download

I have fairly simple route defined:

```
router.get('/download', function(req, res){
  var file = __dirname + 'file.ext';
  res.download(file); 
});
```

It works fine when I'm making requests from my comp, but once I do it from smartphone, server crashes and I get following error:

```
throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
...
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

However, if I after turn fastly server on, smartphone will download it without problem (from previous session).

What am I making wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a browser asks the server for a request with a GET, it sends an ACCEPT statement in the header information.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation#The_Accept.3A_header

So, I'd guess that your browser makes its request and says to the server (in its header) "I can accept graphics files, video files, HTML files, text files, shrimp files*... all kinds of files".  And your cellphone makes the same request but sends a shorter list of MIME types that it can accept.  Maybe you're trying to return a PDF file to your cellphone and it didn't say that it could accept that type since it doesn't have an Adobe Reader app, for example.

So if Express detects that the client can't ACCEPT a PDF file, for example, and it's trying to download a PDF file, it will set the header return code.  And then another part of Express tries to set it again.  If it were me I think I would upgrade my Express version to see if it no longer has this error.

* Bubba Gump humor

Comment: Yes, upgrading my Express did make a change. Thanks!

Comment: Great.  Express recently added that res.download() and added some bugs to it initially, I'd guess.